# Problem to connect my DAPP to Rinkeby smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, dapps, dapp-development

I make small samart contract using Remix and Ganache.
I deploy it to Rinkeby test net and got problem to connect my dapp (small web site) to it. My web3 require.

```
    window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
 // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
  if (window.ethereum) {
    const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    try {
      // Request account access if needed
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      // Acccounts now exposed
      return web3;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  // Legacy dapp browsers...
  else if (window.web3) {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
    const web3 = window.web3;
    console.log('Injected web3 detected.');
    return web3;
  }
  // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
  else {
    const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:9545');
    const web3 = new Web3(provider);
    console.log('No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.');
    return web3;
  }
});

// Initialize Web3

     const Web3 = require("web3")

      const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));

    //const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/0xf2966f689fa2163d9b183933D1fA1Ac044B20915'));

//  const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.currentProvider)

// const web3 = window.web3;

    web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]

console.log(web3.eth.defaultAccount)

      // Set Contract Abi
      var contractAbi = [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_Name",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "registerName",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addressesArray",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address payable",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "_Address",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "checkAddress",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "_Name",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "checkName",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "myAddressInfo",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "namesArray",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "namesArrayLenght",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "ownerAddress",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "address payable",
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "registered",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]; // Add Your Contract ABI here!!!

      // Set Contract Address
      var contractAddress = '0xf2966f689fa2163d9b183933D1fA1Ac044B20915'; // Add Your Contract address here!!!

      // Set the Contract
      var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
```

My Rinkeby contract deploy address - 0xf2966f689fa2163d9b183933D1fA1Ac044B20915. Using Metamask to deploy.

Comment: Hi! I don't see any code here for connecting to the contract - could you include the web3 code you're using to connect, and whatever error message you're getting?

Comment: Hi! I add all web3 smart contract emplementation code with Metamask. It works with Ganache BC. I deploy smart contract in Rinkeby TestNet, but i dont know how to connect web3 to it. Can you help me, plz...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're instantiating the contract using:

```js
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);
```

The [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract) have the following syntax (adapted to your case):

```js
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);
```

Please let us know if that helps!

Comment: This is not sims i need! I think problem in provider. I must specify Rinkeby node, not a local node on my computer